# Class declaration confusion - name between closing brace and semi-colon

Tags: c++, c, oop, class, struct

```
class CRectangle {
    int x, y;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area (void);
  } rect;
```

In this example, what does 'rect' after the closing brace and between the semi-colon mean in this class definition? I'm having trouble finding a clear explanation. Also: Whatever it is, can you do it for structs too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`rect` is the name of a variable (an object in this case).

It is exactly as if it had said:

```
  int rect;
```

except instead of `int` there is a definition of a new type, called a `CRectangle`. Usually, class types are declared separately and then used as

```
  CRectangle rect;
```

as you are probably familiar with, but it's perfectly legal to declare a new type as part of a declaration like that.

And yes, it works for structs:

```
  struct SRectangle { int x, y; } rect;
```

In fact you don't even have to give the type a name if you don't plan to use it again:

```
  struct { int x, y; } rect;
```

that's called an "anonymous struct" (and it also works for classes).

Comment: It's an "unnamed struct", not an "anonymous struct". C++ does not have anonymous structs. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253878/why-does-c-disallow-unnamed-structs-and-unions

Answer (score 2):

It is an object of type CRectangle that is global or belongs to a namespace depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

It declares an instance. Just like:

```
class CRectangle
{
    // ...
};

CRectangle rect;
```

There is no difference between a `class` and a `struct` in C++, except `struct`s default to public (in regards to access specifiers and inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

The one and only difference between structs and classes is that structs have a public default inheritance and access and classes use private as default for both.