# How union is used to define a class

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, visual-c++

I have two doubts, please help me on this:

1. Is it possible to define a class  inside union
2. Is it possible to define a class without class name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 - yes with restriction that class has no constructor or destructor
2 - yes

Following code aggregates both as an example:

```
union MyUnion
{
    class 
    {
        public:
        int a;
        int b;
    } anonym_access;
    double align;

};

int main()
{
    MyUnion u; //instance checks if it is compileable
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to define a class inside union

A union can contain any plain-old-data (POD) type. Types with a non-trivial constructor or destructor are non-POD and, therefore, cannot be used in a union. For such types, you can use [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/variant.html).

> Is it possible to define a class without class name

Yes, it is possible to create anonymous classes, as in:

```
class
{
     // ... body of class ...
} name_of_instance;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253878/why-does-c-disallow-unnamed-structs-and-unions