# Named struct vs. type alias for an unnamed struct

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors

In C++, is it semantically equivalent to have a named struct

```
struct S { int x; };
```

vs. a type alias for an unnamed struct

```
using S = struct { int x; }
```

?

Are there any differences in using the first or second version of S or are those variants completely interchangeable? Or is it very likely that some compiler have issues with the second version?

Comment: Well you can't have one header with the first and another header with the second. And you can't give the second a constructor or destructor

Comment: @M.M - Are you sure about the c'tor and d'tor? Being able to name the class is enough, IIRC. It's just harder to spell out. Edit: NVM, `S` can't be used to name the type http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e9564b0009f5b04

Comment: @StoryTeller: How do you do equivalent of `struct S { S() { std::cout << "C";} ~S() {std::cout << "D";} };` with unnamed struct ? C++ doesn't name constructor `self` or similar.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894450/how-to-add-constructors-destructors-to-an-unnamed-class

Comment: @Jarod42 - If `S` could have been used to name the class itself (which it can't until after the alias is fully defined), then it could work as aliases work with fully named classes. I wrote out of class definitions with aliases like that once, when the original class name was very long. Though it could have been non-standard, I suppose.

Comment: @StoryTeller: We cannot use alias to define constructor/destructor anyway [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8df57d8f94e48041).

Comment: Why would you want to use an unnamed struct with using?

Comment: @Jarod42 - Hence my suspicion it was something non-standard.

Comment: @M.M Ok, let's say I don't want to mix them and I don't need ctor/dtor but only simple data like C struct

Comment: Could there be an issue or anything similar if the type alias for the unnamed struct is used e.g. in a function definition and declaration that the compiler doesn't consider them as equal anymore?

Comment: @ZzetT the first one is unquestionably better, this is purely an academic question

Answer (score 0):

The `using` keyword with that context was introduced in C++11 which means that older compilers that work with the C++98 standard will not be able to compile it.

You will also not be able to forward declare your struct.

As such, no they are not 100% equivalent; but in some cases the using could be substituted for the usual declaration.