# Clang won't compile anonymous struct

Tags: c++, clang++

I have code below:

```
struct Foo {
  union {
    struct {
      double d = 1.0;
      double f;
    };
    char c;
  };
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
}
```

this code works fine with GCC, but when using Clang, it won't compile:

```
main.cpp:13:7: error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'Foo'
  Foo foo;
      ^
main.cpp:3:5: note: default constructor of 'Foo' is implicitly deleted because variant field '' has a non-trivial default constructor
    struct {
    ^
```

What do I miss?

Comment: It’s a GCC extension.  Anonymous are not allowed in the standard.

Comment: @L.F. thanks, you should make this as an answer.

Comment: You might look at `std::variant`which is safer than `union`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253878/why-does-c-disallow-anonymous-structs

Comment: See also [How to add constructors/destructors to an unnamed class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21894450/2173773)

Comment: If you remove the value initialization of `double d` it compiles, i.e. change `double d = 1.0` to `double d`