# How to write a constructor for non-named class

Tags: c++, class

Suppose having a simple class with no name:

```
class {} object;
```

I want my class to have at least one non-default constructor like below

```
class {
public:
    ctor(int member) : _member(member) {}
private:
    int _member;
} object(20);
```

I dont want my class to have a name. Am I able to do such things or am I forced to give a name to the class?

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894450/how-to-add-constructors-destructors-to-an-unnamed-class by the very same guys who would probably have answered it today.

Comment: Why don’t you want it to have a name?

Comment: It is a functor class and will be passed to a thread. I didn't want to give it a name but it came to be impossible.