# Optional member in C++ template based on a numeric parameter

Tags: c++, templates

It there a way to control existence of data members in C++ template based on template arguments?

I have **vec** template which represents N-dimensional vector (like 2D, 3D, 4D…).
Here is the cut:

```
template <typename T, size_t dim>
struct vec {    
    union {
        T d[dim];
        struct {
            T x, y, z, w;
        };
    };
};
```

The idea is that I can access the fields like

```
vec<float,3> vec3;
vec.d[0]=0.0;
vec.d[1]=1.0;
```

with any number of dimensions and for "classical" first four dimensions with the notation above I can use  well-known aliases x,y,z,w, like here:

```
vec.x = 0.0
```

Here “x” is the alias for the d[0].

Having the direct access to the fields is key here, I don't want to have accessors notation; so methods to get access to d don't work for me.

The problem is that for vec<float,2> I don’t need z and w. Is there a way to use something (expect full template specialization) like std::conditional, std::enable_if to control existence of these members?
I’d like to write in the template something like:

```
struct {
    T x, std::enable(dim>1,y), std::enable(dim>2,z), std::enable(dim>3,w);
};
```

It would be nice to avoid boost and other extra libraries. STL would work fine.

Is there any control for this?

Comment: In C++ this is called "template specialization". You will declare specific specializations for your template based on its `size_t` parameter (and likely leave the actual template completely undefined(!) leaving behind only its specializations). This is a highly advanced, and one of the most complicated fundamental aspects of C++ that cannot be adequately explained in just one or two sentences on Stackoverflow. See your C++ textbook for a complete explanation and examples.

Comment: Hi  @SamVarshavchik,
I am well aware of the template specializations. I have long experience with C++.
Please see my initial question carefully. Here is the quote: "Is there a way to use something (expect full template specialization)". I don't want to have specializations since they are risky here. I am quite sure that C++ should have a way to do this inside the template. That's what I am looking for.
And the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61678718/declaring-an-optional-class-field-using-templates-in-c doesn't work for me, since I want to have a condition based on a number, not type.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that in C++, other than specializing the template. `std::conditional`, `std::enable_if_t` cannot be used to declare class members, C++ does not work this way. I am not sure what's so "risky" about specializations. There's nothing more "risky" about them than anything else in C++.

Comment: Can we chat on this site somehow?
Now I am trying:
template <typename T, size_t>
struct v {
};

template <typename T>
struct v<T, 1> {
 T x;
};

template <typename T>
struct v<T, 2> {
 T x, y;
};

template <typename T>
struct v<T, 3> {
 T x, y, z;
};

but it doesn't work for me in the vec template:
template <typename T, size_t dim>
struct vec {
 union {
  T d[dim];

  struct : public v<T,dim> {};

 };

Looking for a workaround. I don't want to specialize the whole template vec. It is risky sine will have code duplication. Can you help with clues?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik
Precisely, I am stuck at why

template <typename T, size_t dim>
struct vec {
 union {
  T d[dim];
  struct {
   T x, y, z;
  };
 };
};

works just fine and (simplified for this example)

struct v2 {
 float x, y;
};

template <typename T, size_t dim>
struct vec {
 union {
  T d[dim];
  struct : v2 {};
 };
};

doesn't. That's what makes my specialization which I use instead of v2 doesn't work. Any clue?

Comment: This piece is pretty close to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34075606/using-inheritance-within-a-union
Any suggestions how this could be solved even with specializations but avoiding to override all vec template>

Comment: Unions are fragile. Better to not mess with it and specialise vec itself. You can further inherit from it for any common stuff.

Comment: @rustyx, the question is how to make this aliasing without duplicating the code for every dimension like 1,2,3,4 while making the specializations? Is there a change to make a partial specialization for this (aliasing) part only?

Comment: Well, I finally implemented this with the partial specializations. I don't like the solution, so I will publish it soon separately and ask for better ideas.