# Can an anonymous union be instantiated in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, unions

I have this piece of code:

```
class test {
  private:
  union {
    double x;
    std::vector<double> y;
  } amIValid;
};
```

I wonder if the union instance `amIValid` is valid?

Comment: when you compiled it, what happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does C++ disallow anonymous structs and unions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253878/why-does-c-disallow-anonymous-structs-and-unions)

Comment: `gcc` gives me this: `note: ‘test::<anonymous union>::<constructor>()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:|`

Comment: So you answered your own question before even posting it? Yes, you need to provide a constructor in such cases, to ensure a single member is active after the object is initialised.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't have an anonymous union. You have a member of an unnamed union type. Anonymous unions inject their members into the enclosing class/union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **unnamed union** can be instantiated in C++:

```
union { int i; double d; } my_thing;
my_thing.i = 3;
// etc.
```

An **anonymous union** is an unnamed union that is [not instantiated (scroll down)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union). You can access its members directly:

```
union { int i; double d; };
i = 3;
// etc.
```

So the answer to the question in the title is that an anonymous union cannot be instantiated because instantiating it means that it is not an anonymous union.