# Anonymous Unions in C++ Contiguous Memory Layout

Tags: c++, standards, anonymous, memory-layout, standard-layout

```
struct Vec0
{
    union { float x, r, h; };
    union { float y, g, s; };
    union { float z, b, v; };
};
```

I wanted to ask, does the C++ standard guarantee this data will be aligned *exactly the same* as if I wrote it

```
struct Vec1
{
    float x, y, z;
};
```

The address `y` immediately follows the address of `x` plus the length for a `float` + padding bits/alignment (I think).

Think it does (guarantee the layout), but was curious if it is *guaranteed* by the ISO C++ Standard?

Update:

To clarify, I am interested in the question, is there any guarantee in the ISO C++ standard that

```
offsetof(Vec0, x /*or r h*/) == offsetof(Vec1, x)
offsetof(Vec0, y /*or g s*/) == offsetof(Vec1, y)
offsetof(Vec0, z /*or b v*/) == offsetof(Vec1, z)
```

This may fall into the category of them being [layout compatible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard-layout)

I am also interested in the sub-case of whether or not the offset of (but not necessarily `offsetof` because one may not be able to use `offsetof` outside the `struct`/`class`/etc., perhaps except in the hypothetical  were it were able to access `private`/`protected` data members outside the `struct`/`class`/etc.) each data member would be the same between the two if all their data-members were made `private`/`protected`.

Also just to note this is not a software design/architecture/best practice question, I am aware there are better ways to access these data members for most cases.

Comment: Note C++ has `std::variant`, unions in C++ are when you look at them in detail not all that nice (a lot of undefined behavior). Also you should in general NOT write code that depends on an actual memory layout. If you do you probably would need to use hints to the compiler anyway (align_as, pack etc...)

Comment: The guarantees are the same, but neither snippet guarantees that there will be no padding between members. (Though in practice there won't be in both cases. Add a `static_assert`.)

Comment: @PepijnKramer OP is using unions to have alternative names for a member. `variant` wouldn't work for this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes that's true. Me triggering on `union` a bit too fast maybe ;)

Comment: Another option if you want to access data with "different" names C++ has something called [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). So you can use `Vec v; auto& [h,s,v] = v; h = 1.0f;`

Comment: That is an option but a little limited for my use case @PepijnKramer

I need to be able to classify types by the names of their members (using concepts) then obtain the offset to each member.

Comment: Even if they have padding it should be uniform right, I know there is a standard that discusses this but Im having trouble finding it rn

Comment: I will update my question to ask if they will have the same alignment rather than continuous.

Comment: In a C++ union, you can only read from the last member written to. So if you write to `x`, only `x` can be read from. You can't read from `r` or `h`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yup that's is exactly what I mean that unions in C++ have too many corner cases

Comment: You *could* also have a `template <char v> float& get()` member function that resolves your desired variable from an `std::array<float,3>` member. So `get<'x'>()` would resolve to the same as `get<'r'>()` and so forth. This would avoid stepping on UB, *and* it would guarantee a small footprint, *and* you very likely can get the compiler to optimise out all the overhead.

Comment: *"Even if they have padding it should be uniform right"* The standard doesn't say anything about that, so no *guarantees*. A struct is allowed to have padding - and that's it. There is no "reasonable" clause.

Comment: I think I may have been thinking of alignment @BoP, not sure though. If true, I am also not sure they would have the same alignment. I also edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Think it does, but was curious if it is guaranteed by the ISO C++ Standard?

It is not, there can be any arbitrary padding between the `union` or `float` members that doesn't have to be consistent between the two examples. This holds in ISO standard C++ as well as ISO standard C.

However, if there is no good reason to add such padding, there wouldn't be any point to it being added. The class layout is part of the ABI and therefore specified in the specification of the C++ ABI or underlying C ABI that your compilation is assuming. You can get definitive answers for your particular compiler/platform combination in the corresponding ABI specification.

---

After edit of question:

```
offsetof(Vec0, x /*or r h*/) == offsetof(Vec1, x)
```

is guaranteed for all choices, because `Vec0` and `Vec1` are [standard-layout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Standard-layout_class) in your example. Therefore all of of these offsets are required to be exactly `0`.

On the other hand

```
offsetof(Vec0, y /*or g s*/) == offsetof(Vec1, y)
offsetof(Vec0, z /*or b v*/) == offsetof(Vec1, z)
```

are not guaranteed in any case by the C++ standard. The padding after the first (and following) members can be different between the two classes, although I don't see any good reason for the ABI to make that choice in your specific example.

> This may fall into the category of them being layout compatible

`Vec0` and `Vec1` are *not* layout-compatible. It already fails the listed requirements in your link because a single non-class member like `Vec1::x` can never be layout-compatible with a (union) class member like the first anonymous union of `Vec0`.

Note that types not being layout-compatible does not mean that their members *won't* have same layout. It just specifies one specific condition under which they effectively have to. The layout-compatibility condition is only relevant for one *very specific* usage of the class, i.e. when both appear as members of a union, in which case there is an exception to the active member rules for that union. That's the only situation in which layout-compatibility has any relevance in the language.

> I am also interested in the sub-case of weather or not the offset of (but not necessarily offsetof because one may not be able to use offsetof outside the struct/class/etc., perhaps except in the hypothetical were it were able to access private/protected data members outside the struct/class/etc.) each data member would be the same between the two if all there data-members were made private/protected.

If not all of the members have the same accessibility (`private`/`protected`/`public`), then the class stops being a standard-layout class and even the guarantee that the first members are at offset zero doesn't hold anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I did update the question to account for length + padding + alignment.

I'm asking if it will be the same alignment between the first and second example.

For example, if the offset will be the same for x in the first and x in the second (accounting for padding + alignment).

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain I am not sure what you mean with "_accounting for padding + alignment_"? The padding can be different between the two. If you substract it, I am not sure what is left that you are concerned about. Although, if you want to get even more exotic, there is no guarantee from the standard that `float` and `union { float x, r, h; }` have the same size either.

Comment: Union's take the size of the largest member: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740577/sizeof-a-union-in-c-c
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union


When I say "account" I mean including, not subtracting. If `Vec` has alignment A, padding width P after `x`, does the second version of `Vec` have the same alignment and padding after `x`/`r`/`h`?

Comment: There can be padding; it can't be arbitrary.  These types satisfy the requirements to be [*standard-layout*](https://eel.is/c++draft/class#prop-3).  So the ABI is expected to precisely define the layout and the C++ compiler is expected to precisely conform to it.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain: At your link is [a counterexample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/740653/103167) to "size of the largest member"

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain There are only two correct answers in that question as far as I can tell. In particular it is wrong that the size of the union is the size of the largest member. Instead it is _at least as large_ as the size of the largest member. The decision to not add padding at the end also isn't required to _only_ be for alignment, although there is probably no good reason to add any more than to assure alignment of all members. Also, in C++ there _is_ a concept of active member which most answers there fail to acknowledge.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain "_If Vec has alignment A, padding width P after x, does the second version of Vec have the same alignment and padding after x/r/h_": That's not guaranteed by the C++ (or C) standard. It should be specified in the ABI in use and I don't see any good reason for the ABI to specify a different alignment or padding in this specific instance. This is what I wanted to say with my original answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt thats the size of a union *member*. The size of the data type is generally not going to vary depending on member access. The example is explicitly noted by Mehrdad's answer. The size of the union itself remains constant. https://godbolt.org/z/893P7WeG4 Though cppreference led me to think that it would be the max size, the union's size is at least as large as the max member size. All union members have the same address as well.

Comment: @user17732522 Your probably right, GCC also tells me they are not layout compatible https://godbolt.org/z/snnbfW5aK I will mark as answer

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain I have updated my answer for your updated question.

Comment: @user17732522 Just saw edit, thanks for additional clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Please note that while the other answer correctly notes that your attempt fails, there is an alternate <strike>expression</strike> formulation that *is* layout-compatible, both internally and with `Vec1`:

```
union Vec2
{
    struct { float x, y, z; } location;
    struct { float r, g, b; } color;
    struct { float h, s, v; } light;
};
```

Many compilers allow you to leave out the names `location`, `color`, `light` as an extension, but this is not standard-compliant.

Comment: That's a good insight! Thanks for the additional answer.

I am unsure if it is non-standard compliant though: 

From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

"Members of an anonymous union are injected in the enclosing scope (and must not conflict with other names declared there)."

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694657/can-an-anonymous-union-be-instantiated-in-c?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C86.3427

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain: This answer contemplates anonymous structs inside a union, different from anonymous unions inside a struct.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct!