# How to apply a comparison operator to each variable in two anonymous structs?

Tags: c++, struct

I have a class with an anonymous struct:

```
class foo {
    struct {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    };
};
```

I create two objects of this class:

```
obj1 = {1, 2, 3};
obj2 = {2, 3, 4};
```

Then I want to know if all the variables of `obj2`'s anonymous struct are greater than the corresponding variables of the anonymous struct of `obj1`.
Is there an easy way to do this apart from directly comparing each pair of variables and some macro stuff?

Comment: `std::tie` would not be used to check whether **all** of the variables are bigger. Only whether the first non-equal one is bigger.

Comment: As I know, std::tie requires an comparison operator implemented in the struct. My struct does not have one.

Comment: @CreFroD `std::tie` is an easy way to create a comparison operator for set of fields. But it would not work in your case as comparison on `std::tuple` works different

Comment: Why do you need this anonymous `struct` anyway? It does not make any sense

Comment: C++ Disallows anonymous structs. It is an extension. Please check the documentation. Similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/2253878/2504757.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overload operators `>` and `<` for your class.This way you don't have to explicitly compare the members every time you need to compare `foo` objects.

```
class foo 
{
  //other members
  public:
  bool operator>(const foo &o)
  {
    return x>o.x && y>o.y && z>o.z;
  }
  bool operator<(const foo &o)
  {
    return x<o.x && y<o.y && z<o.z;
  }
};
```

and then use it as

```
cout<<(obj2>obj1);
```

Answer (score 3):

As an aside, anonymous structs without name aren't a C++ feature.

And then to answer your question, no, there is no shortcut to testing whether *all* members of one struct are bigger than the corresponding members of a second struct.
There is only shortcut to testing whether the first non-equal corresponding member in sequence is bigger using `std::tie`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::tie`:

```
bool foo::allGreater( const &foo f ) const
{
    return not ( std::tie( x, y, z ) <= std::tie( f.x, f.y, f.z ) );
}
```