# Access same elements in array/vector through different ways

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

In C++, is there any data structure allow me to access the elements in array/vector through 2 methods?
e.g.

```
int MemberParam[6];
```

I can access the element like MemberParam[0]..MemberParam[5]. However, if I know

```
0 is height (in CM)
1 is weight (in kg)
2 is age
3 is b-day (year)
4 is b-day (month)
5 is b-day (day)
```

Is there any data structure allow me to access the element in this way:

```
MemberParam.Weight
MemberParam.Height
```

while MemberParam.Weight actually point to MemberParam[1] ?
so that I can access the array/vector element in different way depend on need ?

Thanks.

Regds

LAM Chi-fung

Comment: Create a `struct` instead of an array? An array is a bad way to represent data like this

Comment: You may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253878/why-does-c-disallow-anonymous-structs).

Comment: Also in what scenario would you need to access the data using `operator[]`? It would make the code a lot harder to understand than simple member access (such as `.height`)

Comment: When I write out the data to a file, with [] and index, I can output by using a simple for loop. Real situation involve vector of structure and in turn has over 80 fields in the struct!!!

Comment: You might be interested in having a look at something like Protobuf to serialize your class.

Comment: Yes right, I tried search and find cxxtools and csv++ but they are for Linux (i am working on VC++) ~_~