# Why inherited struct members are inaccessible in union?

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, unions

I have following code which generates error at compile time:

```cpp
struct s { int three; };

union alias {
    struct { int one; };
    struct { int two; };
    struct : s {};
};

int main()
{
    alias a;
    a.one = 1;   // OK
    a.two = 2;   // OK
    a.three = 3; // error: 'union alias' has no member named 'three'
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason members of inherited struct in the union are inaccessible. The main purpose of this code is to provide an aliases to members of struct `s`.

Why compiler doesn't see members of inherited structure? Any options to make them accessible?

Comment: Type-punning with unions is UB by the standard. Use with care.

Comment: You've merely defined the structs within the union, not defined the union members. You need data member definitions, and then your anonymous union will work. The fact that `a.one` and `a.two` are "OK" seems very, very fishy; in fact, I can't get it to compile at all.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, Clang: "warning: declaration does not declare anything".

Comment: What do you thing this `struct { int one; };` should actually declare?

Comment: It should be noted that anonymous structs are not a part of C++; they are a compiler extension. So exactly how they interact with inheritance is... debatable and not governed by the standard.

Comment: @Evg I'm not trying to make type punning. Actually this is simplified version of code with templates which attempts to provide only name aliases for members of `struct s` without changing type[s].

Comment: @Evg accessing inactive members of a union is allowed given that the inactive member has a common initial sequence with the active member and you use only that common initial sequence.

Comment: @NicolBolas very good point. I'll consider to avoid this approach.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, thanks for this note. But is it a common sequence in this case (taking into account the comment by Nicol Bolas)?

Comment: @Evg I would say yes, but I rarely have to play with this particular extension

Comment: @stunpix you'd probably be best off writing a more usual facade (either  a ref-semantics wrapper or just free functions) if this is just for interface compatibility. It's a bit of an X/Y problem I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, after a bit of head-scratching, I think I can explain this correctly. Well, to start things off, this is Illegal As Heck (tm).

A `struct` defined within a union confuses the compiler a bit. If a struct def is followed by a name, a new variable of type of such struct would normally be created, but [C++ explicitly disallows anonymous structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253878/why-does-c-disallow-anonymous-structs). If you omit that name, it could mean two things - either an anonymous struct type is created and then immediately dropped (which meets with a `-Wpedantic` warning), or, as seems to be happening with GCC, it considers it a creation of an **anonymous member of an anonymous type**, which is a non-standard extension:

```
union alias {
    struct { int one; };     // anonymous member of an anonymous type
    struct a { int two };    // no member, just def of "struct a"
    struct { int three; } b; // named (b) member of type anonymous struct
};
```

All in all, you can't really expect this to work... unless you create the union members with explicit type and data member names:

```
struct s { int three; };

union alias {
    struct A { int one; };
    struct B { int two; };
    struct C : s { };

    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
};

int main() {
    alias a;
    a.a.one = 1;   // OK
    a.b.two = 2;   // OK
    a.c.three = 3; // OK
}
```

The whole anonymous union member thing is still a bit puzzling to me, as I can't figure out anything in the standard that would make this work.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think I'll avoid this approach, due to fact that anonymous structs are non-standard language extension.