# Does bitfield count as common initial sequence with a whole int of the same type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, unions

I was wondering if the following was valid C++:

```
union id {
    struct {
        std::uint32_t generation : 8;
        std::uint32_t index : 24;
    };
    std::uint32_t value;
};
```

I want this so I can access both `generation` and `index` separately, which keeping access to the whole number. Since they all are `std::uint32_t`, this shouldn't be UB right?

I plan to use it like that:

```
auto my_id = id{
    .generation = 1,
    .index = 4,
};

auto my_id_value = std::uint32_t{id.value};
```

If it is UB, is there another way to make this work and valid according to the C++ standard?

Comment: _"...Two standard-layout non-union class types may have a common initial sequence of non-static data members and __bit-fields__,..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members

Comment: Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253878/why-does-c-disallow-anonymous-structs) change with C++17/20, by the way? Didn't notice at least...

Comment: @Aconcagua hmm, I totally forgot this was a language extension. The same question applies though.

Comment: @RichardCritten find me the quote in the C++ standard and I'll be satisfied!

Comment: *'In a standard-layout union with an active member of non-union class type T1, it is permitted to read a non-static data member m of another union member of non-union class type T2 provided m is part of the common initial sequence of T1 and T2 (except that reading a volatile member through non-volatile glvalue is undefined).'* – *this* seems to be the relevant phrase...

Comment: @Aconcagua yeah it is! But does it applies to bitfields in the way I posted in the question?

Comment: I cannot imagine differently – there needs to be *at least* one underlying `uint32_t` within the struct to cover the bitfield, and this one would be the common initial sequence... If I recall correctly (again) the compiler is *not* allowed to condense the bitfield to a smaller type if there are only that many bits actually used so that it would fit.

Comment: One thing to note (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field)): *'Multiple adjacent bit-fields are usually packed together (although this behavior is implementation-defined)'* – at least in theory this is not fully portable, even though I'm not aware of any compiler not doing so. In case of serialisation we might have yet another issue as the order in which bitfields are placed into is again implementation defined.

Comment: Current draft - [class.mem.general#23](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#23) - _"The common initial sequence of two standard-layout struct ([class.prop]) types is the longest sequence of non-static data members and __bit-fields__ in declaration order..."_

Comment: It's (at a minimum) implementation defined behavior because bitfields layout isn't specified by the standard. Even with the expected packing of the bitfield you don't know if generation is the LSB or MSB of the uint32_t. If you already rely on the IBD of the bitfield layout you can also depend on the IDB of how the union works for types without common initial sequence.

Comment: Note that the two members of the union have no *common initial sequence*.  That being said, Goswin's comment about IDB is pragmatic.  Unless portability or strict compliance to the standard are concerns.

Comment: Use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) instead of a union if you are able to compile with C++20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By resolution of [CWG 645](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/645.html) (for C++11; not sure whether it is supposed to apply to C++98 as DR) the common initial sequence requires corresponding non-static data members or bit-fields in the two classes (by declaration order) to either be both bit-fields (of the same width) or neither be bit-fields.

The wording for that can still be found in [[class.mem.general]/23](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#23) in the current draft, including an example stating clearly that a bit-field of the same type as a non-static data member will not be part of the common initial sequence.

Therefore the exceptional rule in [[class.mem.general]25](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem.general#25) allowing access to inactive members in the common initial sequence of standard-layout class members in a union doesn't apply in your case and reading `id.value` in `auto my_id_value = std::uint32_t{id.value};` has undefined behavior.