# Strange behaviour of uniform struct

Tags: opengl, glsl

I was working on my OpenGL code, and noticed a weird behavior when getting uniform location from a uniform which has a type of anonymous struct. [Wiki says anonymous structs are prohibited](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#:%7E:text=GLSL%20does%20not%20support%20anonymous%20structures), but I was actually able to create them in vertex shader as a uniform type no problem:

```cpp
uniform struct // no name here! compiled fine!
{
    mat4 device;
    mat4 position;
    mat3 normal;
} uni_transforms;
```

I also tried putting all my `sampler2D` into one uniform struct and ran into a problem: I cannot do anonymous structures where `sampler2D` are present: **the shaders compiled just fine**, but I was not able to get `sampler2D`'s uniform location (and no, the uniform is used in the shader code so it's not discarded as unused):

```cpp
uniform struct
{
    sampler2D diffuse;
    sampler2D specular;
    sampler2D normal;
} uni_textures;
```

I tried adding a type name to the declaration after `struct`, and now (*apparently*) the uniform was there, the location was found.

Why am I able to create anonymous structs when standard says I can't? Why am I not able to create them with `sampler2D`?

*In case implementation matters, I ran this code on `Intel UHD Graphics 620` on `i5-8265U`, Windows 10.*

UPD: Also running fine with anonymous structs (did not test the sampler2D thing) on `AMD Radeon Graphics` on `Ryzen 5 5600H`, Windows 10. Seems that I am the criminal here, not the standard.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, while the wiki is a nice resource, it's not the official standard. If you're not sure what is allowed in GLSL, you should read the GLSL specification.

In this case, the wiki contains partially wrong information. According to [GLSL 460 specification](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf) chapter 4.1.8, structs are defined like this:

> qualifier<sub>opt</sub> **struct** name<sub>opt</sub> **{** member-list **}** declarators<sub>opt</sub>**;**

So struct names are optional, you can omit them. However, the specification also contains this sentence:

> Anonymous structures are not supported.

But the specification gives you an example of it:

```
struct S { float f; }; // Allowed: S is defined as a structure.
struct T {
  S; // Error: anonymous structures disallowed
  struct { ... }; // Error: embedded structures disallowed
  S s; // Allowed: nested structure with a name.
};
```

So while GLSL doesn't support anonymous structs, what they mean by that is you can't define a variable without a name in a struct. But you can create a struct without a name.

The wiki page is correct when it says

> GLSL does not support anonymous structures

but not when it tries to explain what anonymous structures are

> structs without a type name

Comment: When I understood what the standard meant, I immediately found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253878/why-does-c-disallow-anonymous-structs#comment2213295_2253878) for C++. Should've made a distinction between the *unnamed* and *anonymous*, I guess.